# Precision of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: floating-point, scipy, precision, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to calculate the minimal point of function

`f(x)=(x-2e-17)*(x-2e-17)`

with `scipy.optimize.minimize`. 
The expected, *precise* result is `2e-17`. But no matter how I fine tune the tolerence parameters `xtol` and `ftol` of `scipy.optimize.minimize`, it still only gives the *imprecise* result `0` (see below) .  How can we let `scipy` return the  *precise* answer? Thanks.

```
In [35]: scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda x: (x-2e-17)**2,2,method='Powell',options={'xtol': 1e-30, 'ftol': 1e-30})
Out[35]:
  status: 0
 success: True
   direc: array([[ 1.]])
    nfev: 20
     fun: array(4.0000000000000006e-34)
       x: array(0.0)
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 2
```

Comment: You need to renormalize the problem as pointed out below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand your technical problem, but in my opinion it stems from inappropriate use of an optimiser.  I will indulge myself with some philosophical ramblings before answering the question you asked.

---

"Typical" optimisation problems "with useful answers" have optimal function values within a few (i.e. substantially fewer than 17) orders of magnitude of 1 that are attained at a point whose coordinates are all within a few orders of magnitude of 1.  (Or the optimal value is zero, or some of the optimal coordinates are zero.  But users are often still satisfied with very small objective values and coordinates in that case.)

Often, the objective functions fed to black-box optimisers (and their gradients, also fed to some black-box optimisers) aren't written particularly carefully.  Near the optimiser, the computed gradient of f will be dominated by roundoff error.  The gradient may even point away from the optimum.  A black-box optimiser is substantially less useful if it loops forever taking steps of length 0 or bombs out with an error when it gets very close to the optimum, hence parameters with names like "ftol" and "gtol" with fairly liberal default values such as `1e-4`.

Even in the ideal case, where the user provides a function that always returns at `x` the closest floating-point number to `f(x)` and another function that always returns at `x` the correctly-rounded gradient to `f` at `x`, trying to find *the* floating-point vector that minimises `f` is a very ugly discrete optimisation problem.  (NP-hard, if memory serves.)  If `f` is a well-scaled quadratic evaluated in a correctly-rounded way---about the nicest nontrivial case I can imagine---the ugly discrete behaviour starts overwhelming the nice continuous behaviour when you start taking steps of length around `1e-8`.

Methods based on a line search will find themselves computing the minimum over all `t` of `f(x + td)` for some point `x` and some direction `d`.  Consider what `f(x + td)` is in floating-point arithmetic; for some `t`, you compute `x+td` somehow, at best getting the floating-point vector closest to `x+td`, then you plug it into `f`.  In general, this line search will evaluate `f` along a jagged line through `x` meandering in the direction `d`.  Even if `f` is well-behaved and implemented well, the line search can at a fine scale uncover very bad behaviour.  Hence parameters with names like `xtol` that say when to stop a line search.

Lots of methods---pretty much everything I can think of besides straight Newton's method---needs to take some kind of guess about what scale is reasonable for your problem in order to start up.  (BFGS usually takes the identity matrix as an initial guess.  I think L-BFGS takes a unit step for its first step.  Gradient descent methods often try a fixed multiple of the gradient first.  Trust region methods use trust regions, which have to start with some radius.  If you're doing numerical differentiation, your step length needs to be big enough that you're capturing the "continuous" behaviour rather than the "discrete" behaviour of the function, but small enough that you're capturing its fine behaviour rather than its gross behaviour near your point.)

Here, you're optimising a function whose optimal value is zero, attained very close to zero.  In theory, nothing I said above about problems being horrible and their subproblems being horrible needs to apply.  But do you really expect solvers to have a special case for functions whose optimal value is zero, attained very close to zero?  Especially when that's extra code for (likely) reduced robustness?  Why not just feed the solver a well-scaled problem instead?

---

To answer your direct question, Powell's method in scipy calls Brent's line search, starting with the coordinate directions.  Brent's line search, as implemented in scipy, cranks up whatever tolerance you feed it by an additive `1e-11`.  If you hack scipy.optimize so that `Brent`'s `_mintol` is `1e-111` instead, I'd bet you get the desired answer.  (`_mintol` is an absolute tolerance in `x` that's added to the relative tolerance you specify.  It's there so that the line search doesn't waste function evaluations deciding whether to step by `1e-200` or by `1e-201` when either case is likely to result in no step at all.  So don't actually do that.)

Comment: > But do you really expect solvers to have a special case for functions whose optimal value is zero, attained very close to zero?
Here's an alternative point of view: I use a numeric math package when the value I want to calculate isn't expressible in closed form using the standard library math functions. Ideally, I'd simply throw the solver at my problem, and it would solve it, with precision comparable to the standard math libraries.  If, instead, I'm expected to know to normalize my inputs and outputs somehow, that violates the principle of least surprise, for me, and is disappointing.

Comment: [continued] Imagine if the standard library didn't have sqrt(), or perhaps asin() or asinh(); then it seems to me that a reasonable way to implement them would be to tell a solver "find x such that x*x==y"  (or sin(x)==y, or sinh(x)==y, respectively).  I'd expect this to work fine if the inputs and outputs are near zero (certainly when they are on the order of 2e-17), and I'd expect them to be accurate to near machine tolerance.   It's disappointing when that kind of thing doesn't work, and even more disappointing when the deficiency is dismissed as "that's an atypical problem".

Answer (score 2):

From the output, you can see function-value at the found point is 4.0000000000000006e-34, which is much smaller than your ftol=1e-30.

Try pushing ftol down, e.g. to 1e-37.  This should solve the problem.

Alternatively, you can try scaling your function, e.g. instead of `(x-2e-17)**2`, try using the function `1e+34 * (x-2e-17)**2`. The two function have their minimums at the same point.

Comment: Thanks. For info, Pushing down ftol to 1E-50 still does not solve the problem. You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `method` used, for example use "Nelder-Mead":

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda x: (x-2e-17)**2,2,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'xtol': 1e-30, 'ftol': 1e-30})
print(res.x)
```

prints the desired result: `[2.e-17]`

It seems that these types of precision issues seem very tied to the method used for minimization.